# VIM Undofile displays at Terminal login

Tags: vim, zsh, undo, iterm

Upon opening a new terminal window, the most recent VIM undofile to be written displays as the first line, generally with some form of error. *Why is this displaying, and is there any way to prevent it?* Adding `.hushlogin` to my home directory  didn't work.

**Context:** My `.dotfiles` are versioned in a Git repo, containing a symlinked `.Vim` directory. I'm using homebrew installations of `ZSH, iTerm2`, and `Git`.

**Message:** `/Users/joshuaberk/.dotfiles/vim/vim.symlink/undo/%Users%joshuaberk%.dotfiles%system%env.zsh:1: unmatched`

The (potentially relevant) portion of my `.Vimrc` is included below (Undofile settings are in "Backup").

```
" Search/Substitution/Completion
set ignorecase               " removes case sensitivity by default
set smartcase                " adding ≥1 uppercase = case sensitivity
set incsearch                " do incremental searching
set gdefault                 " substitute all matches in line (not first)
set showmatch                " quickly jump to matching bracket
set completeopt=menu,longest " disable preview window on completion
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest,full

" Backup
set undofile
set undodir=~/.vim/undo
set backupdir=~/.vim/backups
set directory=~/.vim/swaps
set history=50
set autoread                 " updates VIM file if changed elsewhere
set hidden                   " hide buffers instead of closing them
set clipboard+=unnamed       " system clipboard by default
```

Comment: This looks more like something to do with Zsh than vim. That undofile ends in zsh: do you have something in your `.zshrc` that tries to find all *.zsh files and load them, or similar?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm using Zach Holman's dotfiles @ https://github.com/holman/dotfiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments, you say you're using [Zach Holman's dotfiles](https://github.com/holman/dotfiles). Within the `zsh` dotfiles, [there's a section that looks for all `*.zsh` files and loads them](https://github.com/holman/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/zshrc.symlink#L14-L22). It's looking for everything under `$ZSH`:

```
config_files=($ZSH/**/*.zsh)
```

Which, by default, is the whole dotfiles directory:

```
export ZSH=$HOME/.dotfiles
```

And your `.vimrc` is setting your undofiles to be within `.vim` (which is a symlink into that dotfiles directory).

---

You can patch around this by removing all those undo files:

```
cd ~/.vim/undo
rm *.zsh
```

But how do you fix it permanently? I couldn't find any especially satisfying way. You can't customise the name of the undofile Vim uses, but you can customise its location. Maybe you're going to tell Vim to save its undos outside of your `.dotfiles` directory:

```
set undodir=/tmp/vim/undo
if !isdirectory(expand(&undodir))
    call mkdir(expand(&undodir), "p")
endif
```

You could tell Vim to not save undofiles for `.zsh` files:

```
autocmd FileType zsh set noundofile
```

Or, you could tell zsh to STFU about errors in your config files by changing your `.zshrc` to print error messages to `/dev/null`:

```
for file in ${(M)config_files:#*/path.zsh}
do
    source $file 2> /dev/null
done
```

This one seems like the worst option; it's going to make your life Hell if you introduce a typo in one of your other `.zsh` files. I'd go for option 1 or 2, depending on how much you want to keep your undo history across reboots.